# How is the Featured Questions list ordered?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

As [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/feature-request-view-featured-questions-latest-first) implies, I suspect that it's a 'newest last' system.

I wanted to double check because at the time I started writing this, a [featured question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1882305) happened to have a negative score before I added the bounty, and I was concerned that this score had caused it to drop to the end.

Comment: I would also like to express the sentiment that it would be nice to be able to control the order in which the items appear without having to use an advanced search.

Comment: I do not know how it works exactly but I think it is more complex than newest last.

Comment: Meta.SE: [Sorting order of featured questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91034/sorting-order-of-featured-questions)